# Understanding Why I have lost so much space mounting a new HDD

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I've just purchased a 4TB Western Digital Red hard disk for my Media Server. I want to understand why I've ended up losing so much space by formatting it as ext4 and then mounting it. I understand some will be lost for the drives own files but what I have lost seems a bit much.

Steps I have taken:

Formatted the Drive using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sde`

Edited FS tab so it auto mounts at boot

```
UUID=3276bc13-20a5-4225-ad33-d8fecdd5216c /wd_red_1 ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Now when I run `df -h` this is my output

```
/dev/sde        3.6T   89M  3.4T   1% /wd_red_1
```

Does it not seem a bit much that in total I have lost 700GB of space?

In comparison I've got a seagate 2TB HDD which I've been through the same process with and it's only taken 200GB (so I have 1.8TB usable). Have I done something wrong?

Server is running 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Can you please have a look (if possible) on the LBA-count of your new HDD ? That is the number of "hard" sectors your drive provides ... now multiply by 512, divide by 1024^4 and you should see 3.6 (rounding rules apply) ..

Comment: How do you know you've lost space?  I don't see any evidence that you checked how much space there was before formatting.

Comment: well certainly he hasn't "lost" space .. there is only a certain amount withheld as @vanadium explains in his answer

Comment: eagle275, see the comment by @steeldriver under the vanadium answer post. Replace "3.2T" with "3.4T" because I think that was a typo (correct me if you disagree, steeldriver), and compare to the output that OP got from _df -h_. His comment is correct. The "missing" 200B is dedicated to the inodes and reserved space. It's a smaller percentage though, compared to the apparent loss of another 400G from translating decimal 4TB to binary 4TiB, using matt's prefered notation.

Comment: Aye the large difference from 4 to 3.6 comes from using the "correct" formula - with 2^40 instead of 10^12 - I am not that used to the overhead that i-nodes bring along, as I'm ntfs / ex-fat used. But I'd guess since 89 MBytes is hardly any space used at all, that there are not many active i-nodes yet ... so most other "lost space" goes to the reserve introduced

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Disc manufacturers list the size in decimal values, so your 4TB HD is actually 4,000,000,000,000 Bytes. But `df -h` lists in binary base numbers (i.e. 4KB is 4096 Bytes, 4MB is 4,194,304 Bytes, 4GB is 4,294,967,296 Bytes, and 4TB is 4,398,046,511,104 Bytes. You only bought a disc with 4,000,000,000,000 Bytes, so that works out to 3.63798807 TB (in the binary number base). This is pretty much exactly the value that you're seeing listed by `df -h`.

You didn't lose any capacity, it's just a numbers game played by the manufacturers.

To check this, try `df -H`. With a capital H, it lists it in decimal values, so instead of "3.6T" it will say "4T" or very close to that number. The manufacturers even go further and the "4TB" they list is also approximate. The actual may be slightly more or less than that.

Comment: It would be useful if df output the [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix](binary prefixes) to avoid confusion. kibi Ki, Mi mebi, Gi gibi, Ti tebi.

Comment: @Matt: I think that would actually cause a lot more confusion, since a great many people have no idea what those mean.  I certainly don't.

Comment: _"You didn't lose any capacity, it's just a numbers game played by the manufacturers."_ - I'd argue that it's a numbers game played by computers. Giga means 10⁹, not 2³⁰. This is true for gigajoules, gigawatts, and gigahertz in your processor. Gigabit Ethernet is also 10⁹ bits/second. Why should storage be any different? Computers should conform to human conventions, not the other way around. Note also that the desktop environments tend to (correctly) show base-10 units for this. Low-level tools could be excused from this, but I agree with @Matt that they'd better use the correct units then.

Comment: ... and that's the argument for introduction of the gibi-  *et. al.* prefixes, @marcelm, but the fact is that that argument received negligible attention until quite recently.  Use of "kilo" to mean 2^10, "mega" to mean 2^20, and "giga" to mean 2^30 has been commonplace in computing jargon for decades.  That *is* a human convention.  You can consider it a matter of dialect.  It probably would never have even been an issue if storage manufacturers had not decided to try to manipulate the mismatch for market advantage, but they did, and now we have dumb "gibi-", etc..

Comment: @jamesqf I'd prefer a moment of confusion of someone learning what `Ti` means compared to the perpetual confusion of which `T` are they talking about! Especially when it's adding ambiguity to SI units.

Comment: _"but the fact is that that argument received negligible attention until quite recently."_ - Hard drives have [pretty much always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte#Consumer_confusion) been measured in base-1000 units. [This article](https://www.ixsystems.com/community/threads/the-great-capacity-non-conspiracy-tib-vs-tb.25265/) agrees this has been the case since at least 1980. Note also that the binary prefixes (GiB etc) have been [proposed in 1995](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix#gibi), 25 years ago. So this is by no means a recent phenomenon.

Comment: @JohnBollinger your "recently" - it's been like 10 years since this started receiving attention.

Comment: @marcelm, the traditional use of "kilo" *et al*  dates to long before before the 80s.  And although storage manufacturers' manipulative practices are nowhere new, it is just as I said: the argument for using binary prefixes *has received negligible attention* until recently, as witnessed by the fact that many IT professionals are still unfamiliar with those prefixes today.

Comment: @marcelm - I partially agree .. but I buy harddrives for TBytes - not Terabytes ... and I hate the manufacturers for taking the easy way out "Formatted capacity may differ depending on the used OS" ...

Comment: I spent the majority of the first decade of this century working at IBM in Storage. We routinely had to address support requests that boiled down to confusion around decimal vs binary representation of capacities. Bear in mind, these requests came from professionals working as storage administrators. I don't think we _ever_ bothered to try and use '-ibi' prefixes in our explanations. We just crunched the numbers, as above, and moved onto the next issue.

Comment: @Matt: I don't think there's "perpetual confusion" in knowing that disk drive manufacturers mislead people about their size.  Maybe some people, like the OP, are surprised, once, when they learn it, but then it just becomes a fact of life, like EPA mileage estimates or 3/4 full cereal boxes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger gibi, etc have been receiving negligible attention since they were created.  10^6 vs 2^20 was source of capacity confusion with HDDs as least far back as the mid 90s when bought a 540/515MB hdd to upgrade my parents PC.

Comment: @jamesqf Agreed for hdd's where it's common. I was more talking about every other domain that has the same problem and not all are as consistent as hdd's. I'd just like it not be ambiguous... and we have a way to do that :)

Answer (score 15):

For sure the accepted answer provided by Rich is the main reason for the observed difference between the specs of the manufacturer and what `df` shows. However, there are some factors that cause you to *really* have less space than what would appear from the capacity of the disk.

Part is due to the **overhead of ext4 file systems**. These systems are very reliable and robust. The structures of the file system need considerable space. You can read about the technical details [here](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout) (with thanks to user Matt).

Another reason is the "**reserved space**" taken, which is a fixed percentage of the total drive capacity. Typically, that fixed percentage is way to high for large drives and especially for data drives. Linux systems reserve typically 5% of new partitions for the root user and system services. The idea here is even when you run out of disk space, the root user should still be able to log in and system services should still run. This cannot happen if there is no space left on the root partition.

You therefore will gain space by decreasing this reserved space. With `tune2fs`, you can adjust that percentage:

```
sudo tune2fs -m 1 /dev/sdb1
```

would reduce the reserved space to 1% on a partition /dev/sdb1 (substitute your own partition here). For a data drive, you probably could set this to zero. However, to prevent too much data fragmentation to build up, an ext4 volume should never be fully filled, so besides to keeping under the maximum storage, you can also leave some reserved space, which also contributes to the remaining free space needed to avoid fragmentation.

Comment: This answer is also a good answer, however this is not the primary reason  for the difference seen.

Comment: This is more relevant to why the 3.6T becomes only 3.2T Available despite only 89M used

Comment: The ext4 layout is described here: https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Layout most of the overhead space is in the inode table on large drives (I think the defaults take 1.6%)

Comment: If the disk is just for large media files, the default inode table is likely too generous. I'd recreate it using the "-T largefile" or "-T largefile4" options which will have one inode per megabyte or one inode per four megabytes respectively.

Comment: 700GB out of 4TB is ~17%, I think not even FAT is that fat, so I suppose you are totally wrong placing the focus here on the administrative overhead of choosing partition type.

Comment: Indeed my answer is as such wrong, but I kept it because it provides some reasons why people effectively have less space available than the total capacity (provided you use the same unit). I now referred to the accepted question, but I think the information I added is also useful in the context of the question.

Comment: If this is strictly for media and not an operating system, I would recommend using a file system with less overhead like `xfs`.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I ran some tests and can confirm that both rich's and vanadium's responses together seem to account for the "700GB (sic.) of space" that the user had 'lost' on their disk. Specifically, the difference between the .4TB of space that seems to have been lost is really the result of `df -h` rendering its output in TiB, not TB. However, the additional .2TiB of lost (this time for real) space seems to be accounted for by the filesystem.

To test this on a comparable operating system (*cough* debian *cough*), I created a 600GB (559GiB) partition. I first made this partition into an ext4 filesystem, which resulted in the following:

```
bucephalopod@corfinium:~# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1             590G   76M  560G   1% /path/to/mountpoint

bucephalopod@corfinium:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda1             550G   73M  522G   1% /path/to/mountpoint
```

Next, I created a new 600GB (559GiB) partition and made it into an xfs filesystem, which resulted in the following:

```
bucephalopod@corfinium:~# df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda2             600G  632M  600G   1% /path/to/second/mountpoint

bucephalopod@corfinium:~# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
...
/dev/sda2             559G  602M  558G   1% /path/to/second/mountpoint
```

That is to say, it seems that the ext4 filesystem accounted for 10GiB smaller disk `Size` vis-a-vis an xfs filesystem, as well as an additional 30GiB less `Available` disk space. The 30GiB in lost availability is 5 percent of the 590GiB disk, which is consistent with the ext4 filesystem's Reserved Blocks percentages. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Reserved_blocks. I would hazard a guess that the 10GiB in lost apparent disk size has something to do with space wasted as a result of ext4's Bytes-per-inode ratio https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ext4#Bytes-per-inode_ratio